# PHP function call was ignored?

Tags: php, forms, email

I currently have a very frustrating problem occuring in my PHP code. There are no reported errors and everything seems to work correctly, except once a function call is made it just seems to not work. I am using the `mail()` function to send out an e-mail which I grab and save as a `.eml` file with `Test Mail Server Tool`. Here is the code leading up to the function call:

```
    if(!empty($email)) {
        if(filter_var(trim($email), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            composeEmail($email, $name, $IDnumber, $othername);
        }
    }
```

I did some standard debugging techniques and outputted the value of the variable inside the `if statement` to make sure that there was actually a value being passed as a parameter, and it returned the value correctly. The real issue is when I reach the `composeEmail()` function.

```
function composeEmail($email, $name, $ID, $othername)
{
    echo ($email);
    $to = "$email";
    $subject = 'Confirmation';
    $txt = 'Body text goes here';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
    $headers = 'From: donotreply@sampleweb.net' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}
```

Some parameters aren't used in that code because I took out their use in the body text to post this example. I have another test form with a function just like this and it works perfectly. The function is called and `Test Mail Server Tool` receives the e-mail and saves it. The output of the e-mail inside the function also doesn't output anything.

I checked for logic errors, checked to make sure the variable has a value, and pretty much anything I can think of. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: `composeEmail($email, $name, $IDnumber, $othername)` and `composeEmail($email, $name, $ID, $othername)` - different ID variables, could be the culprit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll try that out real quick, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: try if( !mail(  $to, subject, $txt, $headers) ){ echo 'email failed'; }else{ echo 'email sent';}  This should print something either way if your code is running that far.  If it fails to send then debug from there etc..

Comment: You have to put `$email` inside double quotes.like, `$to = "$email";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay, I tried it out and now the function is being called. However, the e-mail isn't sent and grabbed. the `echo ($email);` is now being printed inside the function though.

Comment: @Himal - you got it, the op is sending the mail to $email literally, no variable interpolation in single quotes.

Comment: What Himal said also, variables will not get interpolated in single quotes, use doubles or just remove them altogether.

Comment: @Himal Sorry I forgot to reflect that in my post - the `$to = "$email"` is in double-quotes in my code. *Edited original post to reflect that, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Time to take out the **big guns**. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: This line: `$to = '$email';` will assing the value `$email` to `$to`, not the email address you want. `mail()` will fail. You should check the return value of `mail()` for errors rather than assuming it will work. If you have to assign `$email` to something just use `$to=$email;`

Comment: Missing `$` in `subject` also a typo ?

Comment: If you have double quotes try changing the line endings in your header from "\r\n" to just "\n" on some systems the line ending can make a big difference in the email headers..

Comment: Another good catch by Himal. One which error reporting would have caught.

Comment: Also In your headers you are overwriting the value, you have $headers = '...'; on each line  you want  $headers .= '...'; after the first, wont send like that for sure.  that's $headers "dot" =

Comment: @Himal Sorry, another typo! Fred, your suggestion seemed to net me some important info: `Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in (directory)` Something is wrong with the header?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I have this same header set up in another mail function and it seems to work alright though

Comment: You're missing dots in `$headers =` so do `$headers .=` but NOT for the first one.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix / Fred / Himal / Mike It worked! THANK YOU! And thank you to everyone else too! This has been bothering me for such a long time. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: This is the sum content of your headers "From: donotreply@sampleweb.net\r\n" that is what you are sending for the header.  I always use an email class, is this the same machine as the other, is one windows the other linux etc..  even line endings can matter on some servers.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm posting an answer to close it, using some of my comments, if you don't mind.

Comment: Glad I can help I would give the credit to @Himal, the first one to pick up on the syntax issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composeEmail($email, $name, $IDnumber, $othername)` and
`composeEmail($email, $name, $ID, $othername)` - you're using different ID variables.

Plus, you're missing concatenates for your 2nd and 3rd headers.

```
echo ($email);
$to = "$email";
$subject = 'Confirmation';
$txt = 'Body text goes here';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'From: donotreply@sampleweb.net' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

that's why your [**headers**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) are broken.

Plus, what with all the comments left under your question, those should speak for themselves and don't feel I should repeat them here.

- This one has proven to be a group effort. If anyone else who have contributed to the solution and cares to add an answer, I will happy to upvote.

Comment: Confirming the answer worked. Thanks again to Fred -ii-, Himal, Mike, and ArtisiticPhoenix.

Comment: @LoudGraveyard You're very much welcome. I'm hoping that the others will post answers; as I said, I will be glad to upvote their contributions.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted.

Also I would strongly suggest using a simple mail class for this.  While this may seem overkill, it will handle all these header issues for you as well as allow you to use HTML and attachments should you need to.

PHPmailer is a good class http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Rmail is another https://github.com/evpozdniakov/FW/blob/master/lib/Rmail/Rmail.php

I am sure there are plenty more well developed and simple classes to use.  Mail headers can be tricky sometimes.  Especially when you start adding attachments and HTML.  It's better to spend your time designing your site, or business logic.  And, not re-inventing the wheel.

I've seen cases were certain systems are picky when using `\r\n` instead of `\n` and won't send mail without the proper line endings.

As always, glad I could help.